# Post-call/runtime performance implications of Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, v8

If, during the loading stages of a script, many properties are defined using Object.defineProperty, Object.defineProperties or Object.create. And most descriptors are either non-writable (if not accessors), non-configurable, non-enumerable or a combination. Relative to regular assignment or object initialising, what is the passive performance difference if any and the performance difference of accessing the target properties?

I've heard that defining non-writable and/or non-configurable properties involves setting up guards to prevent writing and/or re-definition will be one cause of performance loss, is this true?

Definition example:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: 10
});
```

Comment: I think only benchmarking can tell.

Comment: @Bergi but isn't benchmarking considering a bit troublesome in JavaScript because performance highly depends on context and you shouldn't assume performance off of a few cases as JIT does complex optimisations or something like that?

Comment: Yes. And `defineProperty` impacts those optimisations - we cannot ignore them when arguing about performance.

Comment: @Bergi Would the extent of this impact's effect on performance happen to be known? Or is there any relatively easy way to measure this impact but not on a specific case, rather, mostly in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating properties with Object.defineProperty/defineProperties is definitely slower than just plain assigning them. (How much? Depends. Measure! The best way to make benchmarks relevant is to make them as similar as possible to the real use case you're interested in. Ideally, you measure different versions of your actual production code.)

Reading properties has the same speed regardless of how the property was defined.

Writing to existing properties must always check for writability, precisely because it can't know whether `foo.bar = baz` was used or `Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", {value: baz})`. So that's the same speed too.

There are no special guards.

Comment: About creating properties with the methods, I've read: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/11/performance-implication-object-defineproperty/ but was unsure as to the latter part of your answer; which really clarified how properties work assuming you're right, thank you!